# JQuery Double Scroll - Margin / Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

Well I am using the JQuery jqDoubleScroll plugin to display a scroll bar on top and on the bottom of the div ( which contains a table )

everything looks great in full view, but when the scrollbar appears it

1) hangs off the left side a bit

2) the left and right margins are inconsistent (not equal)

I believe these items are related. I also have a permanent  overflow-y: scroll off the body.

Here is a pen
https://codepen.io/rblanc/pen/jpQbBv

HTML

```
<h1>Recompute on window resize</h1>

<p>Adds the scrollbar only if the bottom one is present, and recompute the top scrollbar size each time the window is resized.</p>
<p>Resize the window to try!!!!</p>

<div id="sample2">
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>AAAAAAAAA</th>
  <th>BBBBBBBBB</th>
  <th>CCCCCCCCC</th>
  <th>DDDDDDDDD</th>
  <th>EEEEEEEEE</th>
  <th>FFFFFFFFF</th>
  <th>GGGGGGGGG</th>
  <th>HHHHHHHHH</th>
  <th> IIIIIIIII</th>
  <th>JJJJJJJJJ</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
  <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
  <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
  <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
  <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
  <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
  <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
  <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
  <td>IIIIIIIII</td>
  <td>JJJJJJJJJ</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll; /**/
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc; 
}

#sample2 {
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 40px;
 }

h1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 26.4px;
   }

  h3 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 15.4px;
  }

 p {
     font-family: Calibri;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-style: normal;
     font-variant: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 20px;
   }

   a {
     color: #ffffff;
   }

   table {
   font-family: Calibri;
   color: #000;
   border-collapse: collapse; /**/
   border-spacing: 0;
   width: 98%; /**/
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 1%; /**/
   padding: 0px;

    display: table; /**/
    border-spacing: 2px; /**/
    border-color: grey; /**/ 
  }

   tr:nth-child(odd) td {}

    tr:nth-child(even) td {
         background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

   table td,
     table th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: #000;
  }

   table tr th {
      background-color: #06A50C; !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Calibri;
     font-weight: bold;
   }






 /* customize scroll */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

 }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }
```

JQUERY

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sample2').doubleScroll({
     resetOnWindowResize: true
  });
  });


 (function( $ ) {

jQuery.fn.doubleScroll = function(userOptions) {

    // Default options
    var options = {
        contentElement: undefined, // Widest element, if not specified first child element will be used
        scrollCss: {                
            'overflow-x': 'auto',
            'overflow-y': 'hidden'
        },
        contentCss: {
            'overflow-x': 'auto',
            'overflow-y': 'hidden'
        },
        onlyIfScroll: true, // top scrollbar is not shown if the bottom one is not present
        resetOnWindowResize: false, // recompute the top ScrollBar requirements when the window is resized
        timeToWaitForResize: 30 // wait for the last update event (usefull when browser fire resize event constantly during ressing)
    };

    $.extend(true, options, userOptions);

    // do not modify
    // internal stuff
    $.extend(options, {
        topScrollBarMarkup: '<div class="doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper" style="height: 20px;"><div class="doubleScroll-scroll" style="height: 20px;"></div></div>',
        topScrollBarWrapperSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper',
        topScrollBarInnerSelector: '.doubleScroll-scroll'
    });

    var _showScrollBar = function($self, options) {

        if (options.onlyIfScroll && $self.get(0).scrollWidth <= $self.width()) {
            // content doesn't scroll
            // remove any existing occurrence...
            $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector).remove();
            return;
        }

        // add div that will act as an upper scroll only if not already added to the DOM
        var $topScrollBar = $self.prev(options.topScrollBarWrapperSelector);

        if ($topScrollBar.length == 0) {

            // creating the scrollbar
            // added before in the DOM
            $topScrollBar = $(options.topScrollBarMarkup);
            $self.before($topScrollBar);

            // apply the css
            $topScrollBar.css(options.scrollCss);
            $self.css(options.contentCss);

            // bind upper scroll to bottom scroll
            $topScrollBar.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', function() {
                $self.scrollLeft($topScrollBar.scrollLeft());
            });

            // bind bottom scroll to upper scroll
            var selfScrollHandler = function() {
                $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());
            };
            $self.bind('scroll.doubleScroll', selfScrollHandler);
        }

        // find the content element (should be the widest one)  
        var $contentElement;        

        if (options.contentElement !== undefined && $self.find(options.contentElement).length !== 0) {
            $contentElement = $self.find(options.contentElement);
        } else {
            $contentElement = $self.find('>:first-child');
        }

        // set the width of the wrappers
        $(options.topScrollBarInnerSelector, $topScrollBar).width($contentElement.outerWidth());
        $topScrollBar.width($self.width());
        $topScrollBar.scrollLeft($self.scrollLeft());

    }

    return this.each(function() {

        var $self = $(this);

        _showScrollBar($self, options);

        // bind the resize handler 
        // do it once
        if (options.resetOnWindowResize) {

            var id;
            var handler = function(e) {
                _showScrollBar($self, options);
            };

            $(window).bind('resize.doubleScroll', function() {
                // adding/removing/replacing the scrollbar might resize the window
                // so the resizing flag will avoid the infinite loop here...
                clearTimeout(id);
                id = setTimeout(handler, options.timeToWaitForResize);
            });

        }

    });

}
```

}( jQuery ));

Comment: Hope this help. You can use `.doubleScroll-scroll-wrapper {overflow: hidden !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

remove margin 1% on the left and right of the table, that's what makes the difference in margin as you said as well as that is the reason why your scroll bar hangs off to the left

Comment: well I would like to keep the 1% margin on the right and left

Comment: well even in that case, remove margin from the table and add it to the `#sample2` and change `width:100%;` on `#sample2` to `max-width:100%;` and accordingly add same margin to the scroll bar and change the width.

Comment: On the table --> changed width to 100% and margin to 0. Also added body > #sample2 { width: 98%; margin: 0 1%;} to div  -  The margins on the table are now correct, but the lower scroll is evenly aligned while the top scroll is off a bit

Comment: And so in the JQuery --> topScrollBarMarkup - I added margin: 0 1%; and it works perfectly